# How to check if an object with the same Id already exist inside a list of objects before adding it?

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# at the moment and I'm trying to make a list of objects. Before adding an object to the list, I want to check if an object with the same id already exist inside the list. (I can't have 2 "merchandise" objects with same "id".)

Here's the code (just realized I named every variable, class and method in French. hope it's still understandable):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    class Marchandise
    {
        private int _id; // attribute I need to check in every object before adding
        public int Id{get; set;} 

        private double _poids;
        public double Poids{get; set;}

        private double _volume;
        public double Volume{get; set;}

        public Marchandise( int id, double poids, double volume)
        {
            this._id = id;
            this._poids = poids;
            this._volume = volume;
        }   
    }

    class Transport
    {
        public double _distance;
        List<Marchandise> _listeMarchandise = new List<Marchandise>();

        public void Ajout(Marchandise marchandise)
        {
            // add function with duplicate check for ID     
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Marchandise m1 = new Marchandise(20,27.6,89.2); //test code
        Marchandise m2 = new Marchandise(20,10.2,5.1);
        Transport t1 = new Transport();
        t1.Ajout(m1);
        t1.Ajout(m2);

    }
}
```

Comment: _id is not an attribute, it's a field, and Id is a property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dictionary` would be better choice over `List`, as `Dictionary` ensures that keys are unique:

```
class Transport
{
    public double _distance;
    Dictionary<int, Marchandise> _listeMarchandise = new Dictionary<int, Marchandise>();

    public void Ajout(Marchandise merchandise)
    {
        _listeMarchandise[merchandise.Id] = merchandise;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the LINQ method [`Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) to check if there is an object which mets a specific condition. In your case you check if there is an object which have such an Id. You can use it like this:

```
class Transport
{
    public double _distance;
    List<Marchandise> _listeMarchandise = new List<Marchandise>();

    public void Ajout(Marchandise marchandise)
    {
        if (_listeMarchandise.Any(it => it.Id == marchandise.Id)) {
            // it already exists, do something about it.
        }
        // add fonction with duplicate check for ID     
    }
}
```